# Batch replace single character in line

Tags: batch-file

I am making a rpg game and got this map system where you select a travel destination, and you move one tile closer to it per move.

What I am wondering is how I can display on my map where the player is.
more specifically I got two variables; `posX` and `posY`. and want to replace the character on line `posY`, character `posX` with a new character that represent the player.

I have tried using `variable:~int,int` to edit a line but the lines have different lengths so that did not work.

EDIT: This is the code that I have been working on below, the `IF !vertical!==!downY!` is never true i think, the `pause` calls are for testing.

```
:DisplayPlayerPos
set /a vertical=27
set /a horizontal=69
set /a downY=%vertical%-%posY%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (SaveGames\Default\World\Color\WorldMap.txt) DO (
    set /a vertical=!vertical!-1
    IF !vertical!==!downY! (
        set left=%%L:~-!%horizontal%-%posX%!
        echo !left!
        set right=%%L:~!posX! + 1
        echo !right!
        set newLine=!%left%X%right%!
        echo. !newLine!
        pause
        Exit /b
    )
)
pause
Exit /b
```

The Map.txt:

```
echo.+---------------------------------------------------------------------+ =========// Travel Map //=========
echo.| 8obo.8:.,-!!::;.::P"-8:,.-P':_,./=,.oodoo-**                          | World: !worldName!
echo.|-+-----+;-+.+++++-+./-::\8-;-8P::P8bP/'                              | Region: Far West
echo.|,8-+---++++-++++++//`=/---_,`:8b8\Y::8....      SENTO                | 
echo.|++-;-'8:`--;`-+++-=:-'       `+.::\_/\--'         X                  | !travelTarget! Position: !travelX!,!travelY!;
echo.|<[/--"--"-::'''+''=    GWEN    +`+-U'                                | Your position: !posX!,!posY!;
echo.|,//    `'"+=/Y=--'+\  FOREST   |:/'|                                 |
echo.|`8b.      ' '|8P\L|,`.        /|/ :b                                 |
echo.||\'b             \\\++'+++-,+'+'---/                                 |
echo.|XX8'              ``:-.--+/-._.+-_,\                                 |
echo.| "'                 /'-+-.``-8+-:dop.                                |
echo.|                       '-'++--+-:                                    |
echo.|                        `-\:"\\'-P>_                                 |
echo.|                             Y"\=="'                   ,-.           |
echo.|      X  THORM                                        /   `.      _.-|
echo.|                                        ,--.         /  +-. `---''---|
echo.|                                     ,-'    `-------'  /   `-+ -`---'|
echo.|                                  ,-' ,. LOGAN      _-'       `----. |
echo.|                                ,' ,-' ;  RIVER ,-''                `|
echo.|                            ,--' ,'   ;    ,---'                     |
echo.|                         ,-'   ,'     ;   /                          |
echo.|                       -/ +---'     ,'  ,'                           |
echo.|                       /   `-------'  ,'                             |
echo.|                     ,'   ,----------'    X                          |
echo.|                   ,'  +-'                  BENDANIA                 |
echo.|                  /  ,'                                              |
echo.|                 |  ,/                                               |
echo.|                 ; /;                                                |
echo.+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this snippet to print the map:

```
:PrintColorFile
set ColorEx=
if /i "%Colors%"=="True" set ColorEx=C
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (SaveGames\%saveName%\World\Color\%1%ColorEx%.txt) do %%A
Exit /b
```

Comment: Any reason you're writing this game as a batch file? Picking almost any other language you can think of would make it easier.

Comment: Personally I think it's a good way to learn the language, I also think it's cool. why?

Comment: I was just pointing out that what you're doing is unusual and likely to get frustrating as you fight against the syntax... there are reasons why most text-based games aren't written as batch scripts. But as a learning exercise it's probably ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q42009080.txt"
:: some random positions
SET posy=7
SET posx=14
:: Add 4 to posx to compensate for "echo." and count-from-0 not 1
SET /a repl=posx+4
SET /a tail=repl+1
SET "me=@"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%" ^|findstr /n "e" ') DO (
 IF %%a==%posy% (
  SET "line=%%b"
  REM just for fun - set `repl` to the character replaced in line
  SET "repl=!line:~%repl%,1!"
  SET "line=!line:~0,%repl%!%me%!line:~%tail%!"
  !line!
 ) ELSE (%%b)
)
ECHO replaced "%repl%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q42009080.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The map file is `type`d into `findstr` with a parameter that will find every line. The `/n` prefixes each line found with `sequencenumber:` so parsing with `delims=:` and using tokens `1` and `*` will put the line number in `%%a` and the line text in `%%b`.

If the line number does not match `posy` then simply execute the line text. If it does match, then transfer the text to `line` as you can't substring metavariables, then replace the `posx`'th character with `me` by concatenating the three required substrings and execute the result.

Note that this routine uses `delayedexpansion` - `line` is the only value that is used where its changing value is required. `%repl%`, `%me%` and `%tail%` will be replaced when the `for/f` is parsed by their then-current values, so the fact that `repl` is changed within the block is of no moment as the code is working with the original value of `repl`.

Of course, it's not critical that `repl` be used to receive the character that is replaced on the line. any normal variable (other than `line`) could have been chosen - I'm just demonstrating the "original values" concept for future readers...